# Get the remainder of a mathematical division without using any arithemetic operation

Tags: code-golf

Write a code that will display the remainder of a division. Code with shortest byte wins.

## Rules:

- No arithmetic operation whatsoever should be in your code
- No use of functions or methods
- If you are using a function or method, it has to be written by you also

## Samples:

```
Sample1: 9/3
Result1: 0
```

```
Sample2: 7/2
Result2: 1
```

Comment: I suppose [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is counted as an arithmetic operation?

Comment: yep. it is. @KyleKanos

Comment: Does it have to be a function, or just an operation

Comment: `If you are using a function or method, it has to be written by you also` So we have to take input of the form `"x/y"` and also write our own string to integer converter?

Comment: scrbinrd3 What's the difference between a function and an operation? (Assuming the operation has a domain and co-domain.)

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting this?

Comment: @MistressDavid Becuase it is a very ill-defined problem. For starters, rules 2 and 3 are contradictory.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I presume Rule 2 is intended to eliminate intrinsic `mod` functions as some languages use that instead of `%` or `!`

Comment: This question is very badly defined.  The inability to use any functions or methods disqualifies most (all?) of the answers I see below.  Functions include `range`, `len`, `map`, and `split`. This may not be @CrowdStar's intent, but that's how it reads.

Answer (score 3):

### J (23)

```
f=:4 :'##~,-.(-y)>\x#1'
```

e.g.

```
   f=:4 :'##~,-.(-y)>\x#1'
   9 f 3
0
   7 f 2
1
```

How it works:

- `x#1`: make a list of `1`s as long as the left argument (`x`)
- `(-y)>\`: divide the list into a `y`-row (right arg) matrix, padding with zeroes.
- `-.`: negate the list (so the padding is `1`)
- `,`: flatten the matrix
- `#~`: replicate each number by itself (so all the zeroes disappear and all the ones remain)
- `#`: count how long the list is now.

Answer (score 2):

## CMD - 48 chars

```
start "" "http://google.com/search?q=%1 %%25 %2"
```

This program leverages the power of the mighty Google to calculate the result. Very rule bendy...

Comment: I'd say `mod` is an arithmetic operation.

Comment: @marinus I'd also say that performing a network request to a site *isn't*. Very rule bendy, but not breaking.

Comment: Also the % characters used in this are not modulo's but used as character substitutions...

%1 and %2 substitute the first and second number; while %%25 substitutes the % sign itself... so technically, the use of %%25 is valid in the actual code itself...

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 46 chars

The challenge is kind of vague, but if string manipulation and regexps are allowed, this should work:

```
($_,$x)=map$"x$_,split"/",<>;s/$x//g;say y///c
```

This code reads a line of the form `7/3` from stdin, and outputs the remainder of the division (in this case `1`).  Needs Perl 5.10+ and the `-M5.010` (or `-E`) switch for the `say` feature.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 38 chars

```
function m($a,$b){return fmod($a,$b);}
```

Comment: modulo is an arithmetic operation...

Comment: I thought it just meant  that there could be no arithmetic operators

Comment: Literal reading has it say, "no arithmetic operations". This basically means we have to do some bit shifting.

Comment: And now functions have been eliminated.

Comment: Hard to write when the rules are constantly changing

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7 - 67 chars

```
n,d=raw_input().split('/')
d=-int(d)
print range(int(n))[d::d][-1]
```

Old answer 87:

Takes a string input and aside from converting it to numbers does no numeric manipulation. The asterisk *looks* like a multiplication sign, but its actually repeated string concatenation ;)

```
n,d=raw_input().split('/')
x="."*int(n)
d=int(d)
while len(x)>d:
 x=x[d:]
print len(x)
```